# How to apply constraints on toolbar item

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

using storyboard, I have a toolbar and added 6 "Item" on it. when running it under simulator for iphone 4s, the 6 items are taking the whole width of the toolbar in portrait mode, while under iphone 6+, is left justified and taking about 3/4 of the space in the toolbar. How can I make these items to evenly distribute on all different iphone?

Thanks
Borna

Answer (score 1):

Figured the solution. I had to add Flexible space bar button between the item